# How to create\merge function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have duplicate code that basically control the Raised background. 
I would prefer one onMouseOver & OnMouseOut function, so code will be more readable.

I assume that this should be a custom hook like but not sure how to do that.

Thank you

```
const [descRaised, setDescRaised] = useState(false);
const descOnMouseOver = () => { setDescRaised(true) }
const descOnMouseOut = () => { setDescRaised(false) }

const [inspRaised, setInspRaised] = useState(false);
const inspOnMouseOver = () => { setInspRaised(true) }
const inspOnMouseOut = () => { setInspRaised(false) }

<Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Card
                        id="descCard"
                        style={{ borderColor: green[500] }}
                        className={classes.card}
                        onMouseOver={descOnMouseOver}
                        onMouseOut={descOnMouseOut}
                        raised={descRaised}> .......


      <Card
                        style={{ borderColor: pink[500] }}
                        className={classes.card}
                        onMouseOver={inspOnMouseOver}
                        onMouseOut={inspOnMouseOut}
                        raised={inspRaised}>.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single `useState` like in the following code:

```
const [raised, setRaised] = useState({
   descCard: false,
   inspCard: false
});

const onMouseOver = (e) => { setRaised(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [e.target.id]: true }));}
const onMouseOut = (e) => { setRaised(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [e.target.id]: false})); }

<Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Card
                        id="descCard"
                        style={{ borderColor: green[500] }}
                        className={classes.card}
                        onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
                        onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
                        raised={descCard}> .......


      <Card id='inspCard'
                        style={{ borderColor: pink[500] }}
                        className={classes.card}
                        onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
                        onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
                        raised={inspCard}>
```

Comment: Hello Monika and thank you for your fast replay. I apologize for the missing piece of code. Wanted to make this question more readable. 
The issue with your solution is that the ID can be null since card contain CardHeader, CardContent etc.

Comment: you can use anything which might be unique to a card, like name. Or if there is not something like that may be add some unique attribute to differentiate between which card is called. You can also pass parameter in onMouseOver and onMouseOut to identify which card is called. :-)

Comment: @angus I would suggest switching `onMouseOver` to `onMouseEnter` to improve performance, `onMouseOver` will be re invoked when moving the mouse over the card and not only once on enter and once on out